# Route params not available when submitting form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, erb, form-for

Why am I getting this error when I submit my form? Haven't I already established the id?

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /polls/:poll_id/responses
Couldn't find Poll with 'id'=
```

In my `Polls_Controller` I am making all of the form inputs accessible. The `poll_id` comes from the route param and the show route responds to `:id` successfully.

```
def show
  @poll_options = @poll.options

  # since you can respond to a poll from its show route
  @poll_response = PollResponse.new
end

def responses
  @poll_response = PollResponse.create(
    params.require(:poll_response).permit(:poll_option_id, :ip_address, :poll_id)
  )
  if @poll_response.save
    redirect_to "/welcome"
  else
  end
end

private

def set_poll
  @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
end
```

My show view loads successfully at `/polls/:id`, however, when I submit my form, it looks like Rails loses access to that param because the route changes.

```
#Poll/Show.html.erb
<%= form_for(@poll_response, url: '/polls/:poll_id/responses/') do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field(:ip_address, value: request.remote_ip) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:poll_id, value: @poll.id) %>
  <ul>
    <% @poll_options.each do |option_id, option_value| %>
      <li>
        <%= f.radio_button(:poll_option_id, option_id) %>
        <%= option_value %> </br>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= f.submit "Vote!" %>

<% end %>
```

Here are my routes. Poll_Response and Poll_Option models belong to Poll.

```
resources :polls, only: [:show, :create, :index, :responses] do
  post 'responses', as: :responses
end
```

Comment: are you calling `set_poll` somewhere? maybe `before_action set_poll, only: [:show]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong here.

First of all, your `url: '/polls/:poll_id/responses/'` option to the form means that the form will use the literal route `/polls/:poll_id/responses/` when submitting the form, `form_for` doesn't understand that you're expecting it to replace the `:poll_id` with anything so it won't.

Next, the route should appear as `/polls/:id/responses` when you `rake routes` so the route itself is probably improperly defined in `routes.rb`. Your `routes.rb` should look more like this:

```
resources :polls, only: [:show, :create, :index, :responses] do
  member do
    post :responses
  end
end
```

That will give you a route like `/polls/:id/response` and you'll be able to attach your `set_poll` controller callback to the `responses` route too. Now when you `rake routes` you should see:

```
responses_poll POST /polls/:id/responses(.:format) polls#responses
```

There's the `responses_poll_path` URL helper for your form:

```
<%= form_for(@poll_response, url: responses_poll_path(@poll) do |f| %>
```

You can also drop the:

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:poll_id, value: @poll.id) %>
```

from your form as the poll's `id` is now in the route where it belongs.

With the above changes, your form will be posting to the right controller,  `params[:id]` in that controller will identify the poll in question, and `@poll` will be the right thing inside your `responses` controller.

Now that you have the route and form properly set up, your controller becomes much simple:

```
@poll_response = @poll.responses.create(
  params.require(:poll_response).permit(:poll_option_id, :ip_address)
)
```

The `@poll.responses` association should supply the poll's `id` automatically (if you have a `has_many :responses` inside `app/models/poll.rb` of course).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've triple checked your instructions. I should note that my responses model is `PollResponse`. If I run 
    ```@poll_response = @poll.responses.create(
      params.require(:poll_response).permit(:poll_option_id, :ip_address)
    )```
I get the following error:
```NoMethodError at /polls/11/responses`
undefined method `responses' ```

Comment: So you don't have `has_many :responses` in your `app/models/poll.rb` then?

Comment: I have a `has_many :poll_responses, dependent: :destroy`. I tried running `@poll.poll_responses.create(` but forget to refresh my db ui when I tried that. That works now =)